# Phase/Amplitude Forumla in R for Fourier Transformation

Tags: r

So I am trying to find 3 things given a certain function in the x domain when transformed into the spectral domain.

1. the Amplitude
2. The Frequency
3. The Phase

In R (statistical software) I have coded the following function:

```
y=7*cos(2*pi*(seq(-50,50,by=.01)*(1/9))+32)
fty=fft(y,inverse=F)
angle=atan2(Im(fty), Re(fty))
x=which(abs(fty)[1:(length(fty)/2)]==max(abs(fty)[1:(length(fty)/2)]))
par(mfcol=c(2,1))
plot(seq(-50,50,by=.01),y,type="l",ylab = "Cosine Function")
plot(abs(fty),xlim=c(x-30,x+30),type="l",ylab="Spectral Density in hz")
```

I know I can compute the frequency manually by taking the bin value and dividing it by the size of the interval(total time of the domain). Since the bins started at 1, when it should be zero, it would thus be  frequency=(BinValue-1)/MaxTime, which does get me the 1/9'th I have in the function above.

I have two quick questions:

First) I am having trouble computing the phase, is there a prebuilt R function that can give me the phase? From a manual calculation, the density function peaks at 12 (see bottom graph), shouldn't the value then the value of the phase be 2*pi+`angle[12]` but I am getting a value of

```
angle[12] [1] -2.558724
```

which puts the phase at 2*pi+angle[12]=3.724462. But that's wrong the phase should be 32 radians. What am I doing wrong?

Second) Is there a function that can automatically convert `abs(fty)[12]=34351.41` , to the amplitude number I have in front of the cosine, which is 7?

[image]

Comment: I would have expect phase to be in range 0 - 2*pi